# How can I find a conversation thread that contains exactly the specified participants using SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm dealing with conversation threads that may have multiple participants.

I have a SQL table that maps looks like this:

```
Table: conversation_participants

conversation_id  participant_name
---------------  ----------------
1                Al              
1                Bob             
1                Carl            
2                Al              
2                Carl            
3                Bob             
4                Al              
4                Bob             
5                Carl
```

Given a set of `participant_name`s, I would like to be able to find the single `conversation_id` that contains exactly those participants, if one exists. Can someone help me determine the SQL required to achieve this?

I've gone through various different approaches, and I think that this works:

```
-- Given:
--   participant_names: a list of participant names, like ('Al', 'Bob')
--   n: size of participant_names
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_participants
WHERE participant_name IN participant_names
AND conversation_id IN (
  SELECT conversation_id
  FROM conversation_participants
  GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING count(*) = n
) 
GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING count(*) = n;
```

The subquery first produces `conversation_id`s that have exactly `n` participants. Then the `WHERE` clause filters to include each row of a conversation that contains exactly `n` participants that corresponds to one of the participants in `participant_names`. Finally, the last `GROUP BY` causes us to exclude any `conversation_id`s that did not produce exactly `n` rows from the `WHERE` query.

However, the above query seems very complex and redundant (to me) for something that should fairly straightforward. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option removing the `where` criteria and using `conditional aggregation`:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_participants
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING sum(case when participant_name IN participant_names then 1 else n + 1 end) = n
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dcd2/5)

Comment: Given the sample table in my original post, when `pariticpant_names` is `('Al', 'Bob')`, this returns both `conversation_id` = 1 and 4. It should only return `conversation_id` = 4, since that is the only conversation that includes exactly 'Al' and 'Bob'. `conversation_id` 1 also includes 'Carl'.

Comment: @MichaelTingley -- oops, didn't read that clearly enough.  take a look at the edits.  you can use `conditional aggregation` for this.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with conditional aggregation, but running the following query: `SELECT conversation_id FROM conversation_participants GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING count(*) = count(case when participant_name IN ('Al', 'Bob') then 1 end)` produces the results `conversation_id` 3 and 4 for me :(

Comment: @MichaelTingley -- yeah, I see your issues.  updated the answer with a potential work around though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_participants
WHERE participant_name IN participant_names
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING Count(*) = n
```

Comment: Given the sample table in my original post, when `pariticpant_names` is `('Al', 'Bob')`, this returns both `conversation_id` = 1 and 4. It should only return `conversation_id` = 4, since that is the only conversation that includes exactly 'Al' and 'Bob'. `conversation_id` 1 also includes 'Carl'.